# FireFox still not working for Protractor/Selenium tests?

Tags: selenium, firefox, jasmine, webdriver, protractor

I have a project suite of automation tests that uses Protractor and Jasmine.  As of a couple months ago, my tests stopped working in FireFox.  Everything works perfectly in Chrome, and almost perfectly in IE.. because why would IE work ya know.

There have been multiple posts about this and I've read through all of them, but I haven't been able to determine if there's a workaround/solution to this.  It's not entirely a HUGE deal if my tests run in FireFox, but with a web application it's mighty nice to be able to test all instances.

Basically what happens when I run a test in FireFox:

1. Command prompt acts like everything is about to run properly (FireFox driver starts up.. server remains running etc etc)
2. Firefox opens for a split second (icon appears on the task bar, browser flashes on the screen and closes)
3. After a good minute or so protractor gives me the following message:

`[firefox #01-0] WebDriverError: Unable to connect to host XXX on port XXX
after 45000 ms.`

With a ton of DEBUG lines referring to JSON files and Firefox addons.

Any thoughts or other sources I could check out would be sweet.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: Just updated to latest Protractor and Webdrivers and issue still occurs.  Would this be a possible firefox version issue?

Comment: yes might be, which firefox version are you using? did you upgrade it anytime? rule of automation if your scripts are stable and working on a browser version do not change your configuration until required!

Comment: Current/ish version of 47.0.1 - I think the automatic upgrades were enabled for a while without me noticing.

Comment: Downgraded to 43.0.1 and 33.0.1 and still doesn't launch properly.  Any idea on the last known version to work?

Comment: Latest version of protractor works fine in FF 47.0.1 version, give it a try

Comment: I've been running 47.0.1 and that's where i noticed my initial errors.  So no it's not working for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with latest Firefox support from latest selenium-server. Use `geckoDriver` and it will work.

Follow this [URL](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2403)

Comment: I thought I heard rumor of the FF version messing it up.  I'll give this a try today and update the thread with results.

Comment: Still haven't been able to figure this one out.  Do you happen to have something with snippets from a config file or other sources I could look at to get this geckodriver working in protractor?